# How should I get Heroku Toolbelt to use 2.0.0 instead of system default on OS X?

Tags: ruby, heroku

I installed Heroku Toolbelt on my Macbook Pro (running OS X 10.7.5) by way of the [PKG file](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/osx).

Unfortunately, heroku is not utilizing my rbenv-specified global ruby version (2.0.0-p195), but seems to be defaulting to the OS X system ruby version that came with the OS (1.9.3).

```
› heroku version
heroku-toolbelt/2.39.3 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
```

This is causing issues as I try to wrap up my upgrade from rails 3.2 to 4.0.0.rc1.

How can I tell Heroku to use 2.0.0-p195 instead of 1.9.3 when using the toolbelt?

I tried completely uninstalling the toolbelt and reinstalling it from the pkg file, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The misunderstanding was mine here.  The version used by Heroku Toolbelt is not a relevant detail, and is specifically sett o 1.9.3 in the latest version by Heroku.  See [this answer](https://github.com/heroku/toolbelt/issues/53).

The problem that drove me to ask this was that my 'git push heroku master' was failing to install activesupport because it was using 1.9.2 server-side.

Updating my Gemfile to include the following just below the rubygems.org line, checking in the Gemfile, and then pushing to Heroku again solved my original problem:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran across the error `Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.1` when shelling out to the `heroku` command in a rake task - which comes from Heroku Toolbelt.

The answer, as specified [here](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/400#issuecomment-18744931) by https://github.com/fnichol is to wrap the task like this:

```
# Rakefile
task :freedom do
  Bundler.with_clean_env { sh "heroku" }
end
```